# boost::asio only works when run within Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost::asio::io_service and boost::asio::deadline_timer from a secondary (i.e. non-GUI) worker thread.  This works perfectly when the program is run from within Visual Studio (2010).  However, when I run the release executable outside of Visual Studio, the async_wait()/run() combination doesn't seem to do anything.

I have confirmed that run() does indeed block.  I have also now confirmed that the debug executable works fine, it is only the release executable that does not work (i.e. the function specified in async_wait() is not run).

Perhaps there is some project setting, some optimization I need to disable, or something?

Comment: Do you get errors at runtime or merely behavior you didn't expect?

Comment: No error, just the function specified in async_wait() does not run.

Comment: Try building in debug and see what happens if you run it from outside VS

Comment: Ah, interesting, indeed debug executable works fine.  This is confusing!

Comment: @Dave : Sounds like you have an uninitialized object somewhere in your code.

Comment: @ildjarn: how could an uninitialised object cause a program to run fine in all circumstances, except for the release executable running outside of the Visual Studio IDE?  What exactly do you mean by uninitialised object?

Comment: @Dave : I mean a default-initialized object of scalar or POD type. Debug builds (or, potentially, builds whose process is launched with VC++'s debugger attached) typically zero-initialize these while release builds do not.

Comment: @ildjarn: wow, thanks for the pointer.  Sorted now!  Actually, strangely, was the other way around.  Release executable running outside of the IDE initialised a pointer to NULL, whereas all other configurations, inside and outside of the IDE, did not initialise to NULL.  I check for a NULL value in an if-block, expecting false when the program is first executed (and whilst running), until the program terminates and is being cleaned up.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Reposting from comment so the question can be marked as answered)

You probably have an uninitialized variable somewhere, i.e. a default-initialized object of scalar or POD type.